# to get all records from a table with two where clause and then call the columns in the variables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I want to get all column records from a table with two where clause and then I want to assign each column to a variable to call somewhere. I have tried this but there is an error in debug error log file

Method:

```php
$user_match = MemberExtra::where('left_bv', '>=', 1)->where('right_bv', '>=', 1);
$user1 = $user_match->user_id;
$ref_id = $user1->referrer_id;
$ref_user = User::find($ref_id);

$user1 = $user_match->user_id;
$ref_id = $user1->referrer_id;
$ref_user = User::find($ref_id);

$ll_logg = LendingLog::where('user_id', $user1);
```

Error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$user_id

and second error:

> Property [user_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

this error is coming in the second line:

```php
$user1 = $user_match->user_id; ///here is the  error
```

what mistake I am doing?

Comment: try this one `MemberExtra::where([['left_bv', '>=', 1], ['right_bv', '>=', 1]])->get();`

Comment: @codeformoney you can't call a property on a collection either

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_match = MemberExtra::where([['left_bv', '>=', 1], ['right_bv', '>=', 1]])
  ->get()
  ->map(function($user_match) {
    return [
      'user_id' => $user_match->id,
      'ref_id'  => $user_match->referrer_id,
    ]
  });
```

Comment: Property [user_id] does not exist on this collection instance. this is the error I am getting after using your code. I have tried to get user_id from above code in a variable like this $user_iidd = $user_match->user_id;   $ll_logg = LendingLog::where('user_id', $user_iidd);

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: @AliUsman can i see you `migration` code for this specific `MemberExtra`